# js: inject several scripts without createElement/appendChild after all

Tags: javascript, post

Having a string with several  tags given, i have to insert them - if possible at once, without parsing the string to extract the separate scripts:

> > decodeURIComponent("%3Cscript%20src%3D%27%2F%2Ftest%2Fdg-48119-137488.js%27%20async%20defer%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E%3Cscript%20src%3D%27%2F%2Ftest2%2Feg-48119-137488.js%27%20async%20defer%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E").replace(/+/g,"%20");

I tried with createElement("DIV"), adding the string's content with .innerHTML and appendChild(theDIV). The html content looks fine, but the scripts did not load :-(

What else can I do to get the script post-loaded (without parsing the string before)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this isn't working because the code you posted uses an invalid regular expression.

`+` is a reserved character in regex. Try instead using `.replace(/\+/g,"%20");` 
(note the escaped `+`).

Comment: Hi, the replace is and was already inside the code. it's even in the post above. or are we talking about different ones?